# How to construct form data (key-value pairs) from raw html in python?

Tags: python, html, forms

is there any library that does this ?

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#constructing-the-form-data-set

Here an example of what i want to achieve:

```
data = """
<form action='/'> 
<input type='text' name='test'>
</form>
"""

x = buildformdata(data)

print(x)
{'test': ''}
```

I know how to create this using for ex. beatifulsoup, but maybe theres something done already? For example, what about converting code that Firefox or Chrome uses to build that data into python?

Here's some code that does this:

https://github.com/jmcarp/robobrowser/blob/master/robobrowser/forms/fields.py

https://github.com/jmcarp/robobrowser/blob/master/robobrowser/forms/form.py#L64

Comment: Similiar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30964568/how-to-get-a-key-value-data-set-from-a-html-form

Comment: Another one with javascript https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624/convert-form-data-to-javascript-object-with-jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heres source code from chromium :))

https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/build/third_party/zope/testing/formparser.py